# スクリーン、ウインドウ、ブラウザ、ページ、レイヤーの違い。座標に関して、スクロールした時に影響を受けるのは？

Tags: javascript

**JavaScriptで座標処理を行いたいのですが、基本用語が分かりません**
・下記認識で合っているでしょうか？

---

**モニタのスクリーン領域**
・常に固定
・screenY。スクロールしても影響なし

**ブラウザのクライアント領域**
・可変
・pageY。スクロールすると影響あり
・clientY。スクロールしても影響なし

---

**質問**
・「ウインドウ領域」「レイヤー領域」「画面領域」「ページ領域」とは？
・上記何れをさす言葉？　それとも別の概念？　あるいは文脈によるので一概には言えない？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MouseEvent の各プロパティの話であれば、[CSSOM View Module](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#extensions-to-the-mouseevent-interface) にまとめて定義されています。

- screenX/Y: スクリーン領域（出力デバイスの領域）からの距離
- pageX/Y: 初期包含ブロック（ルート要素など）からの距離
- clientX/Y: viewportからの距離
- offsetX/Y: `event.target` のpadding edge（paddingの外側）からの距離

よって、マウスカーソルを動かさずページ全体をスクロールした際に変化しないのは、 screenYやclientYということになります。一方、マウスカーソルの位置に何かを表示したいといった場合にはページ上の相対位置で指定する場面が多いですから、この場合はpageYやoffsetYを使うことになります。

その他の言葉については、画面・ウィンドウ・ページに関しては見ての通りだろうと思いますが、レイヤーに関しては微妙です。少なくともHTMLやCSSにそのような概念はなかったはずです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: viewportとはブラウザ描画部分のことでしょうか？　リンク先で「pageY」は「associated Window object」と書かれていますが、page(document)はブラウザとは異なる概念ですか？　「Window object」って何を指すのでしょうか？　例えば、ブラウザを最大表示した状態で左上にマウス配置した場合は、screenもpage(document)もviewsp‌​ortも同じ座標となるでしょうか？　それ‌​ともviewsportだけはブラウザの上‌​部分があるので、絶対に同じ座標にはならない？

Comment: @re9 Window objectはDOMのwindowオブジェクトのことです。表示領域([viewport](http://qiita.com/ryounagaoka/items/045b2808a5ed43f96607))上にはスクロール位置に応じてWebページ(page/document)の一部が表示されていますが、そのスクロール位置は `window.scrollY` で取得できますよね？いわゆる最大化ならタイトルバー部分で差が出ますが、F11等で全画面表示をすればscreenYとclientYと（スクロー‌​ルしていなければ）pageYは0になるように‌​思います。

Comment: F11で全画面表示してみたら、screenYとcli‌​entYと(スクロー‌​ルしていない状態の​）pageYは同じ位置になりました。参考になりました